# How to use BeautifulSoup to wrap body contents with div container

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How can I wrap `<div data-role="content"></div>` around the contents of html body with beautiful soup?

I tried to start with the following but haven't been able to make any progress:

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(u"%s" % response)
    wrapper = soup.new_tag('div', **{"data-role":"content"})
    soup.body.append(wrapper)
    for content in soup.body.contents:
        wrapper.append(content)
```

I also tried using body.children but no luck.

This appends the wrapper to the body, but doesn't wrap the body contents like I need

-- edit --

I've gotten to here, but now I end up with duplicate body elements like this `<body><div data-role="content"><body>content here</body></div></body>`

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(u"%s" % response)
    wrapper = soup.new_tag('div', **{"data-role":"content"})
    new_body = soup.new_tag('body')
    contents = soup.body.replace_with(new_body)
    wrapper.append(contents)
    new_body.append(wrapper)
```

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(unicode(response))
wrapper = soup.new_tag('div', **{"data-role":"content"})
body_children = list(soup.body.children)
soup.body.clear()
soup.body.append(wrapper)
for child in body_children:
    wrapper.append(child)
```

Answer (score 3):

I recently hit upon this same situation, and I'm not content with any of the other answers here. Iterating through a massive list and rebuilding the DOM doesn't seem acceptable to me performance-wise, and the other solution wraps the body, not the body's contents. Here's my solution:

```
soup.body.wrap(soup.new_tag("div", **{"data-role": "content"})).wrap(soup.new_tag("body"))
soup.body.body.unwrap()
```

Very simply, this approach just wraps the body twice, first with the new tag, then another body. Then I use BeautifulSoup's unwrap method to delete the original body while maintaining the contents.

Answer (score 0):

A perfect use case for BeautifulSoup's `wrap()`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag

response = """
<body>
    <p>test1</p>
    <p>test2</p>
</body>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')

wrapper = soup.new_tag('div', **{"data-role": "content"})
soup.body.wrap(wrapper)

print soup.prettify()
```

prints:

```
<div data-role="content">
 <body>
  <p>
   test1
  </p>
  <p>
   test2
  </p>
 </body>
</div>
```

UPD:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = """<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>test</p>
</body>
</html>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(response)

wrapper = soup.new_tag('div', **{"data-role": "content"})
soup.body.wrap(wrapper)

print soup.prettify()
```

produces:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>
   test
  </title>
 </head>
 <div data-role="content">
  <body>
   <p>
    test
   </p>
  </body>
 </div>
</html>
```

Comment: wonder why your version works.  when I tried that I ended up with two body elements.  is it because of the 'html.parser' argument to BeautifulSoup()?  Why does my version fail and your version work?  Does your version work with a complete html page like <html><head><title>test</title></head><body><p>test</p></body></html>?

Comment: @user319862 `html.parser` doesn't make any difference here, see that it works for your example (`UPD` section).

Comment: How odd.  Wonder what was going on with my code in December.  I ended up going a different route to display error pages in a modal popup with javascript instead of manipulating it on the server side, so I don't have the code to test this any longer.  Going to mark it as accepted since your code appears to work.  Thanks

Comment: @user319862 thanks, hope the code would help somebody else in the future.

Comment: Oh, I just reread your answer.  Your div is wrapped around the body.  not the body contents

Comment: @user319862 Oops, I was thinking you need to wrap the body with the div as the question states. Then, instead of `wrap`, you can just set the body's `name` and `attrs` to wrapper's `name` and `attrs`: `soup.body.attrs = wrapper.attrs;soup.body.name = wrapper.name`